# SQL Server performing slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance

I have a Microsoft SQL Server running on an IBM server with 10 cores and 64 GB RAM.

I have from 100 to 300 users working concurrently on the server.

Users complain about slowness of the application.  I've checked the server and found CPU usage is 6%, RAM usage is 4GB, and network usage is up to 1Mbps.  I have a 4Mbps dedicated line.

I've tried to collect other information on the server such as `Blocking` and `Wait Statistics`:

[image]

[image]

The Average resource wait time is 40 sec.

I am unable to interpret the cause. Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this?

If any further information is required, I can provide that.

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I've added the following items:

**Page Life Expectancy 3**

[image]

**IO stats Snapshot**

[image]

**Wait Statistics**

[image]

**Server information**

[image]

**Memory status**

[image]

**Query Execution List**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following discussions in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap), we've established:

- 32bit Enterprise SQL Server.
- 3.5GB of memory in use (no AWE/PAE).
- 2.1GB database with 1.3GB buffer pool.
- Page life expectancy of 3 seconds.

Suggested fixes are:

- AWE/PAE as a quick fix so the database fits in memory.
- Investigate the frequently called, highest IO queries identified.
- Consider rebuild to 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

I think main problem is that SQL Server is not using all RAM you have (32 bit windows?). you can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280359%28v=sql.105%29). You should make sure sql server ir using much more than 4 GB of ram (in your case- up to 60 GB ([recomendations](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/suggested-max-memory-settings-for-sql-server-20052008/))).

After you enable server to use RAM and if that still not enough, you could probably apply some (or all) of these steps:

- optimise tempdb (file location = different disk/file count = CPU cores/2)
- optimise log files (separate disk)
- use read only file groups (less locking)
- depending on disks you have- create more files per file group and put them on seperate disks
- If that is OLTP system- set Max degree of parallelism = 1

With all server settings be careful and think twice before apply them.

Comment: The last advice is actually a non-advice. Who said parallelism is bad and needs to be disabled?!

Comment: @Marian Paralelism not bad per se. but there are specific situations when configuring MAXDOP to 1 helps a lot. From question i saw a lot of CXPACKET waits, so that makes me suspicious about this setting.

Comment: @Jãnis,  Large cxpacket waits in combination with high pageiolatch_xx could indicates large or many table/ clustered index scans. in this case viable explanation. Be careful, a lot of the time Cxpackets waits hides the true root cause of the problem.

Comment: @Jānis: That's exactly what I was afraid of. Lots of CXPacket waits is not that bad as it sounds :-). Usually you should ignore that wait type unless there's a situation like the following: [Parallel parallelism](http://www.brentozar.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/parallel-parallelism.png) :D. Some info: [Hands off Maxdop](http://sqlskills.com/blogs/brent/post/SQL-Server-Virtualization-Get-Your-Hands-Off-That-MAXDOP.aspx), [Hurry up and wait](http://sqldoctor.idera.com/wait-stats/parallelism-hurry-up-and-wait/), [Stop waiting](http://sqldoctor.idera.com/wait-stats/parallelism-stop-waiting/).